# Redux-observable epic dispatch two actions

Tags: redux-observable

I have the following epic in redux-observable

```
export const landingEpic = action$ => (
    action$.ofType('LOAD_USERS').delay(5000).map(() => ({
        type: 'USERS_LOADED',
        UserList: ['a','b','c','d']
    }))
);
```

So far I am fine, however I want the epic to dispatch a 'LOADING_USERS' action so that I can display a processing message, while the users are being loaded.  Is the epic the right place to do this, and if so how do I do this.  If the epic is not the place to do this then where do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is to immediately emit USERS loading and then after 5 seconds emit USERS_LOADED

There are many ways of doing this, here are two:

```
export const landingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('LOAD_USERS')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.of({
        type: 'USERS_LOADED',
        UserList: ['a','b','c','d']
      })
        .delay(5000)
        .startWith({
          type: 'LOADING_USERS
        })
    );

export const landingEpic = action$ => (
  action$.ofType('LOAD_USERS')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.timer(5000)
        .map(() => ({
          type: 'USERS_LOADED',
          UserList: ['a','b','c','d']
        }))
        .startWith({
          type: 'LOADING_USERS
        })
    );
```

The key here is that we need to use `mergeMap` (or `switchMap`, etc depending on your use case) to isolate our top-level chain so that we can create an Observable that produces two actions at different times. `startWith` is also handy, but could also use `concat` for the same effect:

```
Observable.concat(
  Observable.of({ type: 'LOADING_USERS }),
  Observable.of({
    type: 'USERS_LOADED',
    UserList: ['a','b','c','d']
  })
    .delay(5000)
)
```

Comment: Hey tmp dev did this answer it for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like the following:

```
const landingEpic = action$ => (
action$.ofType('LOAD_USERS').delay(5000).flatMap(() => (Observable.concat(
{
    type: 'USERS_LOADING'       
},
{
    type: 'USERS_LOADED',
    UserList: ['a','b','c','d']
}))));
```

Comment: but doesn't this mean that I have to wait 5 seconds even before USERS_LOADING is emitted.  What I want to do is to immediately emit USERS loading and then after 5 seconds emit USERS_LOADED